# What is the dimension of the space of planes in $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, grassmannian, homogeneous-spaces

What is the dimension of the space of planes in $\Bbb R^3$ and how do we reach the answer?

*Clarification: What I am searching for is what is the least number of parameters that I need. For example, the space of all directions in $\Bbb R^3$ would have dimension $2$, the space of all lines - dimension $4$.*

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Would you please indicate your own thoughts about and work on the problem so far? (Among other things, this will help potential answerers write more useful replies.)

Comment: In what way is the space of planes a vector-space?  How do we define addition on said space?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm not sure whether this is what OP means (it's hard to say from the question), but there's a natural smooth manifold structure (sometimes this manifold is called $Gr(2, 3)$ or $(\Bbb P^2)^*$) on the set of planes in $\Bbb R^3$; this is a special case of the *(real) Grassmannian* $G(k, n)$, the space of $k$-planes in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Travis I'm aware of that, I'm in the same spot here.

Comment: Sorry for the loose usage of terminology. What I am searching for is what is the least number of parameters that I need. For example, the space of all directions in {R^3} would have dimension 2, the space of all lines - dimension 4.

Comment: @KristianGeorgiev then it seems that you're looking for a crash course in some manifold theory.

Comment: In short: the "dimension" is $2$.  Note that this is not *immediately* the dimension in the sense of the dimension of a vector space.

Comment: A quick justification: specifying a plane through the origin is the same as specifying a line perpendicular to that plane.

Comment: To be sure, though, I assumed you mean lines and planes through the origin.  If we want the space of lines (or planes) placed arbitrarily in space (that is, we allow "translation" of the planes), then our spaces grow in dimension.

Comment: Yes, assuming the lines and planes are through the origin. Thank you.

Comment: @KristianGeorgiev In that case, the space of lines through the origin is just the projective plane $\Bbb P^2$, which is $2$-dimensional not $4$-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, I was confused because in the paper I read it was not stated whether the lines and the planes should be through the origin or not.

Comment: @KristianGeorgiev For the space of planes (not necessarily) through the origin, one can use the approach in my answer, but $GL(3, \Bbb R)$ does not act transitively on that space so we must replace it with a group that does. A natural choice is the affine group $GL(3, \Bbb R) \ltimes \Bbb R^3$, which has a convenient matrix embedding in $GL(4, \Bbb R)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we already know that the space of directions in $\Bbb R^3$ is $2$ (indeed, it can be identified with the unit sphere $\Bbb S^2 \subset \Bbb R^3$), we can see that the space $\Bbb P^2$ of lines (through the origin) in $\Bbb R^3$ also has dimension $2$ (the map $\Bbb S^2 \to \Bbb P^2$ that sends a direction to the line through the origin parallel to that direction is a $2:1$ covering).

On the other hand, if we pick any inner product on $\Bbb R^3$, we get for free a bijection from $\Bbb P^2$ to the space $(\Bbb P^2)^*$ of planes through the origin in $\Bbb R^2$, which identifies a line $\ell \in \Bbb P^2$ with the subspace consisting of all vectors orthogonal to $\ell$. Thus, in the topology induced by this bijection, the space of all planes through the origin in $\Bbb R^3$ also has dimension $2$.

---

Alternatively, the group $GL(3, \Bbb R)$ acts on $\Bbb R^3$ by matrix multiplication and maps lines through the origin to lines through the origin, so it acts on the space $(\Bbb P^2)^*$, and it's easy to see that this action is transitive. On the other hand, the stabilizer in $GL(3, \Bbb R)$ of the $xy$ plane,
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\ast\\ \ast\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right\},$$
is
$$H := \left\{\begin{pmatrix}\ast & \ast & \ast\\ \ast & \ast & \ast\\ 0 & 0 & \ast \end{pmatrix}\right\},$$
so we can identify $(\Bbb P^2)^*$ with the homogeneous space $$GL(3, \Bbb R) / H,$$
which (as a topological manifold) has dimension $$\dim (\Bbb P^2)^* = \dim (GL(3, \Bbb R) / H) = \dim GL(3, \Bbb R) - \dim H = 9 - 7 = 2.$$

By an analogous argument, the *(real) Grassmannian* $Gr(k, n)$, that is, the space of $k$-planes through the origin in $\Bbb R^n$, has a natural topological manifold structure with dimension $k (n - k)$.

Comment: @KristianGeorgiev You're welcome, I hope you found it useful.